# "type `()` cannot be dereferenced" when pushing to a Vector in a HashMap

Tags: rust

I am working through the exercise in the Rust book, chapter 8. But this question is not specific to the exercise. Its specific to this line: `*entry.push(name)`. I am trying to dereference entry to get the vector to push in my value, but I get this error:

```bash
error[E0614]: type `()` cannot be dereferenced
  --> src/main.rs:36:17
   |
36 |                 *entry.push(name)
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

According to VSCode's Rust analyzer, the types for `entry` is `&mut Vec<&&str>`. I suspect the `&&` instead of a single `&` maybe whats causing the issue. But I am not sure why VSCode thinks that. Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Here is the full code:

```rs
use std::{io::{self}, collections::HashMap};

fn main() {
    let mut store = HashMap::new();

    loop {
        println!("Enter a command:");

        let mut command = String::new();

        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut command)
            .expect("Failed to read command");

        let split_command: Vec<&str> = command.split_whitespace().collect();

        match split_command.as_slice() {
            ["Add", name, "to", department] => {
                let entry = store.entry(department).or_insert(Vec::new());
                *entry.push(name)
            },
            ["Exit"] => {
                break;
            },
            ["Show", ..] => {

            },
            [_, ..] => {

            },
            [] => {
                println!("No command!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

You're trying to dereference `entry` which is entirely unnecessary, because method calls automatically dereference anyway.

Furthermore, `*` has pretty low binding power in Rust, so what you wrote parses as

```
*(entry.push(name))
```

So you try to dereference the result of [`Vec::push`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.push), which is `()`, which is not a pointer, thus can not be dereferenced, which is exactly what the compiler tells you:

> type `()` cannot be dereferenced

Comment: I see! Thanks for the insight. I did try it without the dereferencing and I am running into "borrowed value does not live long enough" on the command. But I believe that is an entirely different problem that I am going to dig into. 

I do understand dereferencing slightly better now!

Comment: The lifetime problem you have is probably that `split_command` is a bunch of references to `command`, which is only valid for a single iteration of the loop. At the end of each iteration, `command` is dropped, and thus all references to it (including the one that's in the vector) are invalid. Also the store keys, the Entry API is great but it wants owned values. So what you need to do is allocate both `department` and `name` by using e.g. `.to_string()` on them.

Comment: That makes sense! And changing them to String with `.to_string()` fixed it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

There is a priority problem. Currently, your code is understood as `*(entry.push(name))` rather than `(*entry).push(name)`, which is probably what you intended, which is why you get an error (`entry.push(name)` has type `()`, which you cannot dereference).

However, that is useless, as the dot operator `.` in Rust will automatically add any amount of reference (`&` or `&mut`) and dereference `*` required, which is why Rust is able to type `entry.push(name)`.